# ajax call and window.location

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a shopping cart and I'm having some difficulties with a concept.
Basicly, I remove two articles in a certain condition and it works perfectly.

My problem is that I want to redirect the user instantly if these two articles are removed from the cart.
When I enter the window.location, it is refreshing the page but it's not updating the cart from the ajax call.

So what I want to achieve is that after these two ajax calls, i want to be redirected but also, the ajax call should do their things in the delete_item.php :)
I'm using jQuery inside a normal javascript file on a certain function.

```
function deleted(id, pozitie) {
    var msg = 0;
    $(document).ready(function(){                    
        $('.' + id).each(function() { 
            $(this).remove();
            $('.sm').remove();
            ajaxpage("delete_item.php?id="+pozitie+"&ord="+ordrno,"error");
            ajaxpage("delete_item.php?id="+(pozitie+1)+"&ord="+ordrno,"error");
            window.location="http://mypage.com/offer";
            msg = 1;
        });
    });
```

Comment: I think your AJAX calls are not “done” when the location gets changed and therefor a new “main” request is started – so the browser just cancels those AJAX requests at that point. Either change location only when _both_ requests have finished (callback-based) – or don’t use AJAX here, just have your `delete_item.php` accept multiple IDs to delete, and have it itself redirect to the desired endpoint (maybe based on an additional GET parameter, if it should not redirect under all conditions).

Comment: This is new for me, what is ajaxpage?

Comment: probably you have to trigger some event in ajaxpage() when it is done and listen for two 'done' events to make redirection.

Comment: use redirect as callback

Comment: Thank you guys, I'm gonna check the callback method.
@roasted -> this is an older type of ajax library that I use, I cannot rewrite the functions due to some complications atm :)

Comment: Thats ok so just change this function to accept a callback if its not already the case (which i doubt) .  Oops, didn't see @Sudip Pal's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `callback` function and redirect your page if your ajax call return success. Hope it works.

```
ajaxpage("delete_item.php?id="+pozitie+"&ord="+ordrno,"error",callbackfn);
```

Callback funfction:

```
function callbackfn(){  
window.location="http://mypage.com/offer";  
}
```

Comment: I am gonna try this now, never thought about the callback :)

Comment: If you need any code reference, view source the common.js file in one of my site www.fruzer.com, you will find the ajax function and the callback function.